# Xpath getting multiple img's in div

Tags: objective-c, xpath, tfhpple

I'm working with TFHpple and I would like to get all of the image url's in a single div tag, the number of images can very so it would need to be dynamic. Here is the HTML

```
<div id="images" class="content">
      <div class="galleria">
<img data-thumb="https://s3.amazonaws.com/nakedapartments/images/78659582/mthumb.jpg?1453414352" alt="" class="hidden" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/nakedapartments/images/78659582/large.jpg?1453414352" />

<img data-thumb="https://s3.amazonaws.com/nakedapartments/images/78659608/mthumb.jpg?1453414354" alt="" class="hidden" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/nakedapartments/images/78659608/large.jpg?1453414354" />

<img data-thumb="https://s3.amazonaws.com/nakedapartments/images/78659634/mthumb.jpg?1453414356" alt="" class="hidden" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/nakedapartments/images/78659634/large.jpg?1453414356" />
</div>
    </div>
```

So far I've only been able to fetch the first one and adding the src to an array using this path:

```
//div[@class='content']/div[@class='galleria']/img
```

Can any one point me in the right direction for getting all src attributes that exist in the div into my array? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XSLT template for satisfying this task would be

```
<xsl:template match="//div[@class='content']/div[@class='galleria']/img">
    <xsl:value-of select="@src" />
</xsl:template>
```

The according XPath-Expression for getting the values of all `src`-attributes would be

```
//div[@class='content']/div[@class='galleria']/img/@src
```

That should get you all the required values of the `src`-attributes, but in XSLT this doesn't work - for a reason that is unknown to me. Maybe someone has an idea?